# Doctrine innerjoin

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine, inner-join

This is the Doctrine-code in a ZF-application:

```
$rowset = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select("cu.clientuser, cu.usertitle, u.firstname")
    ->from('Model_Db_Tblclientuser cu')
    ->innerJoin('cu.Tblusers u')
    ->whereIn('cu.clientid', (int)$clientid)
   ->execute();


foreach ($rowset as $row) {             
    $list[] = array(
        'title' => $row->usertitle,
        'firstname' => $row->firstname
    );
}
```

The query that's been generated is this one:

```
SELECT 
    t.clientuser AS t__clientuser, 
    t.usertitle AS t__usertitle, 
    t2.userid AS t2__userid, 
    t2.firstname AS t2__firstname 
FROM 
    tblclientuser t INNER JOIN tblusers t2 ON t.userid = t2.userid 
WHERE 
   (t.clientid IN (1))
```

copy-pasted into phpmyadmin, it gives a perfect result.
But when I run the ZF-application it goes wrong...

For the field "clientuser" everything is working well.
But for the field "firstname" it's going wrong...

```
Unknown record property / related component "firstname"
on "Model_Db_Tblclientuser"
```

What do I do wrong?

Very strange thing to notice: if I do

```
foreach ($rowset as $row) {             
    var_dump($row);
}
```

it outputs stuff from total other tables as well, tables who don't matter at all...

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into the same issue a while back and resolved it by selecting the ID on the join.

Try adding..

```
->select("cu.clientuser, cu.usertitle, u.id, u.firstname")
```

Or whatever the joining key is and see if this resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to perform a massive select instead of a custom select ?

```
->select("cu.*, u.*")
```

Or maybe remove the select. I know it's not a solution and (from a doctrine user in symfony) every thing seems ok in your code. Are you using the 1.2.4 ?

ps: "save your browser, don't var_dump a doctrine 1.x object" :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but if anyone runs into this problem I believe that it is related to a similar on I experienced.

Please see the solution here: [Doctrine Query Builder Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089490/doctrine-query-builder-bug)